# How to get GestureDetector working correctly

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I have this code so far in my Activity:

```
private class SwipeGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    // Swipe properties, you can change it to make the swipe 
    // longer or shorter and speed
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 200;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
      try {
        float diffAbs = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());
        float diff = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
        Log.d("MainDisplayActivity", "Gesture class is running");
        if (diffAbs > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
          return false;

        // Left swipe
        if (diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
           MainDisplayActivity.this.onLeftSwipe();

        // Right swipe
        } else if (-diff > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
          MainDisplayActivity.this.onRightSwipe();

        }

      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("YourActivity", "Error on gestures");

      }
      return false;
    }

  }//end of SwipeGestureDetector class

  //methods called by SwipeGestureDetector when the approrpiate swipes occured
  private void onLeftSwipe() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully have the swipe working for left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  private void onRightSwipe() {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully have the swipe working for right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

and I have this global: `private GestureDetector gestureDetector;`

and on `onCreate` I have this because its what I have seen people do:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SwipeGestureDetector());
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parent_main_display)).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong, but nothing is happening when I swipe. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you debug and see logcat (e.g: `Log.d("MainDisplayActivity", "Gesture class is running");`)?

Comment: @SaDec Yes sir. in fact, nothing runs. Not even the onTouchEvent which doesn't make any sense. At least touch should work, but it never runs. As you can imagine, that leaves me in a tough position because if there is no erro, how can I fix it -_-

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10426238/1559448) will help you…

Comment: Well that answer is what I am doing. Doing all that in `onCreate`. But now it opens up a new question. Should I not be using the onTouchEvent on the parent but the individual children `View`s?

Comment: @SaDec, you really did help :) So I was going about it slightly wrong.I was setting the `onTouchEvent` to the root View of the Activity, but the problem with that is its not reachable I guess. Since the children `View`s cover it, it doesn't get invoked, which in my opinion is strange, but makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You should ovveride the next

```
@Override
 public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
  return true;
 }
```

also onFling should return true

Comment: Why override it when I don't need it? But thanks for pointing out that onFling should return true. It did not work though.

Comment: @Andy because of true in this methods indicate to gesture detector to process event, not to skip. behavior is different from onClick

Comment: Thats understandable, but I thought it just ran the behavior it normally had, which would return true... right? But didn't work :/ I'm trying to figure out why its not doing anything, but I can't find anything really wrong with the code, and its the same as everyone else has done it.

Comment: @Andy I dont know what to suggest to you...look in source code of SimpleOnGestureListener and try to understand in which cases SimpleOnGestureListener  process onFling

Comment: @Andy I had the same problem, what I did was create an interface with functions like onTap, onLeftToRightFling, etc.  I then moved my onclick logic into the onTap function.  Hope this helps.